# How to save array of json object to mongoose?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save array of object to mongoose schema but it is failing to load data into `laptop` schema i only see one insertion that contains `id`.
 How can i save array of json object to mongoose schema ?

controller.js

```
var laptopData = [
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'HP'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'HP'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'},
{ name: 'Hp probook 15.1',cpu:'2.4GHZ' ,ram: '4GB', harddrive: '160GB',Brand:'Hp'}
]
var laptop = new Laptop({laptopData});
laptop.save(function(err) {
  // we've saved the dog into the db here
  if (err) throw err;

});
```

schema.js

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

var LaptopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  ram:String,
  harddrive:String,
  Brand: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Laptop', LaptopSchema);
```

Comment: check [Storing Json Object in Mongoose String key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497875/storing-json-object-in-mongoose-string-key)

Comment: Please post user mongoose schema also over here to help debug

Comment: @georoot schema added to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should individually create objects and save them. You can't pass an array like that. Use something in the lines of

```
var laptopData = [...];
for(var laptopItem in laptopData){
    new Laptop(laptopData[laptopItem])
      .save()
      .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err.message);
      });
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy approach :)