# How do I get a json and save it to a mongodb subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm getting a json with this structure:

```
"quality": [
                {
                    "cod": "000000",
                    "month": "09/2021",
                    "average": [
                        {
                            "status": "0",
                            "type": "....",
                        },
                        {
                            "status": "0",
                            "type": "....",
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "cod": "0000123",
                    "month": "10/2021",
                    "average": [
                        {
                            "status: "0",
                            "type": "....",
                        },
                        {
                            "status: "0",
                            "type": "....",
                        },
                    ]
                },
```

I can access this array with this line of code:

> response.data.data[0].quality[0].average

I'm declaring the model like this:

```
var averageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status: String,
  type: String,
  
});
.
.
average: [{averageSchema}],
```

I can manipulate and access each one and save, but I can't all. I can save separately like this:

```
const Datas = db.dados_produtivos;
.
.

status = response.data.data[0].quality[0].average[0].status
type = response.data.data[0].quality[0].average[0].type

const data = new Data({
    .
    .
    quality: [{
        "cod": cod,
        "month": month,
        average: [{
            status: status,
            type: type,
        }],
    }],

.
.
.
    await data.save();
```

How can I save everything at once?
I tried to loop to save the data, but I couldn't manipulate it.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834360/how-to-save-array-of-json-object-to-mongoose) to make the loop, but to no avail:

I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze.

Answer (score 0):

you can construct an `average` array by mapping response data to `averageSchema` data, then set it as stored value

```js
const Datas = db.dados_produtivos;
.
.
averages = response.data.data[0].quality[0].average.map(a => ({ status: a.status, type: a.type }))

const data = new Data({
    .
    .
    quality: [{
        "cod": cod,
        "month": month,
        average: averages,
    }],

.
.
.
    await data.save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The array is saved in the correct amount, but only the _id is saved!